# Another indentation problem within minipage using Overleaf

Tags: indentation, minipage, cv

I will have to write my master thesis soon, so now I'm learning tex using Overleaf. I started with making resume, which I constantly have issues with indentation. I came across a lot of suggestion and tried them, but my indentation still looks wrong.

[image]

As you can see from the picture, the last item in my minipage always have different indent, eventhouh I have set the indent as `\noindent`. Here's my code. I've been struggling like for 2-3 days. I'd appreciated advice & suggestion. [updated my code]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage[margin=.1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist{noitemsep,topsep =0pt,parsep =0pt,partopsep =0pt,leftmargin =*}

\titleformat{\section}
{\titlerule\addvspace{5pt}\normalfont\bfseries}
{}
{0cm}
{}[\titlerule]

\titleformat{\subsection}
{\footnotesize\bfseries}
{}
{0cm}
{}

\titlespacing{\subsection}
{0cm}
{.5cm}
{0cm}

\newcommand{\ul}{University of Landscape}
\newcommand{\uoa}{University of Architecture}

\newcommand{\entry}[4]{
    \begin{minipage}[t]{.15 \textwidth}
    \small\textsc{#1}
    \end{minipage}
    \begin{minipage}[t]{.80\textwidth}
    \bfseries\footnotesize #2

    \textit{\hspace{-.12cm}\footnotesize }#3
    {\normalfont #4}\end{minipage}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.7\textwidth}
\section{Education}
    \entry{2010 - 2013}{\ul}{\emph { Thesis : City Landscape Visualization using Augmented Reality}}{\begin{itemize} \item Diploma 3 in Architecture Engineering 
    \item GPA 3.63 (Cum laude Honor)
\end{itemize}}{}
    \entry{2014- 2016} {\uoa}{\emph{ Thesis : City Landscape Design using Probability Method}}{\begin{itemize} \item Bachelor in Architecture Design .\item GPA 3.53 \end{itemize}}{}
\entry{2017 - Now}{Unievrsity of College}{\emph{ Thesis : Improving Architecture Accuracy \\}} {Master candidate in Architecture Design }
\section{Seminars}
\entry{2010}{Guide Hand-Design for Beginner}{}{\ul}
\entry{2013}{Work-space within the Virtual Reality Scope}{}{\ul}
\entry{2013}{Workshop in Photography in the Green Living Creativity}{}{\ul}
\entry{2014}{Creative Architecture Industry}{}{\uoa}

\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

Comment: (1) welcome, (2) why on earth do you have `\noindent\vspace{...} ` as a part of the width argument for minipage. I would think that would give an error, that really does not belong there.

Comment: it isn't clear why you have any minipages at all, you are also missing a lot of `%` from ends of lines in the definitions so introducing extra spaces in the output.

Comment: I removed the overleaf tag as this is unrelated to where you run tex.

Comment: I assume I did wrong stuff. I'm just starting like few days ago and still figuring things put. I followed some tutorials but somehow mine's looks weird. Also I just tried to delete the \noindent\vspace{} and the output is still the same

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I want to add another minipage later on the right side for my personal info. But as for now I'm still having trouble with this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I'm not convinced of this strange setup, I think the following fixes several of your issues. I'd recommend you to read an introduction to latex though, and not just some random guides in the internet. Have a look at [What are good learning resources for a LaTeX beginner?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/11/97512).

I think it's a good start to do your CV in latex from scratch, but just for reference, there are already a lot of beautiful CV templates out there.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage[margin=.1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist{noitemsep,topsep =0pt,parsep =0pt,partopsep =0pt,leftmargin =*}

\titleformat{\section}
{\titlerule\vspace{2pt}\normalfont\bfseries}
{}
{0cm}
{}[\titlerule]

\titleformat{\subsection}
{\footnotesize\bfseries}
{}
{0cm}
{}

\titlespacing{\subsection}
{0cm}
{.5cm}
{0cm}

\newcommand{\ul}{University of Landscape}
\newcommand{\uoa}{University of Architecture}

\newcommand{\entry}[4]{%
  \begin{minipage}[t]{.15\textwidth}%
  \small\textsc{#1}%
  \end{minipage}%
  \begin{minipage}[t]{.80\textwidth}%
  \bfseries\footnotesize#2

  \ifx#3\empty\else\textit{\footnotesize #3}\fi

  {\normalfont #4}\end{minipage}\par\addvspace{2ex}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.7\textwidth}
\section{Education}
  \entry{2010 -- 2013}{\ul}
    {Thesis : City Landscape Visualization using Augmented Reality}
    {\begin{itemize}
      \item Diploma 3 in Architecture Engineering 
      \item GPA 3.63 (Cum laude Honor)
     \end{itemize}}{}
  \entry{2014 -- 2016}{\uoa}
    {Thesis : City Landscape Design using Probability Method}
    {\begin{itemize}
      \item Bachelor in Architecture Design
      \item GPA 3.53
     \end{itemize}}{}
  \entry{2017 -- Now}{University of College}
    {Thesis : Improving Architecture Accuracy}
    {Master candidate in Architecture Design}

\section{Seminars}
\entry{2010}{Guide Hand-Design for Beginner}{}{\ul}
\entry{2013}{Work-space within the Virtual Reality Scope}{}{\ul}
\entry{2013}{Workshop in Photography in the Green Living Creativity}{}{\ul}
\entry{2014}{Creative Architecture Industry}{}{\uoa}

\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

[image: result]

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping me improve my messy code, looks a lot cleaner now. Also for the recommendation, I will carefully take a look of it.

Comment: You're welcome! If this helped you out, you can accept the answer, so others don't see this question in the unanswered questions anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Following suggestion from [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/LaTeX/comments/9420dp/another_indentation_problem_within_minipage_using/), it was because the last line isn't being justified. So I need to add

```
\unskip\parfillskip 0pt \par
```

at the end of `\entry` command. And it works !